# Discard rows with non-consecutive numbers in Google BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have dataset with field containing repeating numbers sequence (1 - 5 for brevity), and some rows with the number out of sequence:

```
1
2
3
5 -- out of sequence, need to discard
4
5
1 -- sequence starts over
2
3
4
...
```

How do I discard rows that are out of sequence?
Thanks!

UPDATE: There is other column to specify the ordering.

UPDATE2: Dataset for testing:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT * FROM
  UNNEST([
    STRUCT(1 AS id, 1 AS n),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 5),
    (5, 4),
    (6, 5),
    (7, 1),
    (8, 2),
    (9, 3),
    (10, 4)
  ])
)
```

UPDATE3: There can be many numbers out of order (from the same 1 - 5 range). The sequence always starts with 1, and all numbers are present, except the last round, which can be incomplete (ending earlier, see the test set). The out-of-order numbers are like a "noise" that needs to be removed.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  What column is used to determine ordering?

Comment: example provided is quite simplified and does not present generic case (at least to me). Can you clarify logic of exclusion (just one out of order row or it can be many and so on) and  logic for what to survival rows (should they represent whole set 1-5 or can be partial? etc. - for example if sequence is 1,2,3,5,3,4,1,2,3,4 - will survived numbers will be 1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,4? without those type of details  - answering here is just shooting into the air :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for the comment, see update3, answer for your sequence is 1,2,3,4 (all other are discarded, because it should go the whole round before starting the new one, except the last round)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and with use of JS UDF
Tt returns all found sequences started with `1` and with following consecutive numbers

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extract_sequence(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, n INT64>>) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, n INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  target = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var result = [];
  j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arr[i].n == target[j]) {
      x = [];
      x.id = arr[i].id;
      x.n = arr[i].n;
      result.push(x);
      j++
    } 
  }
  return result;
""";
WITH t AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(1 AS id, 1 AS n), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 1), (8, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4)
  ])
)
SELECT elem.id, elem.n, grp
FROM (
  SELECT grp, extract_sequence(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, n) ORDER BY id)) arr
  FROM (
    SELECT id, n, COUNTIF(n = 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) grp
    FROM t
  )
  GROUP BY grp
), UNNEST(arr) elem
ORDER BY id
```

with result as expected:

```sql
Row id  n   grp  
1   1   1   1    
2   2   2   1    
3   3   3   1    
4   5   4   1    
5   6   5   1    
6   7   1   2    
7   8   2   2    
8   9   3   2    
9   10  4   2
```

Hope you will adjust to you specific case

Answer (score 3):

Let me assume that you have another column to specify the ordering.  If not, the problem is not well-defined.

If so, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(col) over (order by row) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_col is null) or 
      (prev_col = col - 1) or
      (prev_col = 5 and col = 1);
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: @AfanasiiKurakin . . . That seems doubtful.  Are you using the right `order by` column?

Comment: your answer gives 1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4 result, should be 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4 - I'm using order by the "other column"